# Jenkins cannot run rake with homebrew installation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jenkins

I did following to install jenkins on my Mac for a ruby on rails project with a rspec test suite

1- installed with brew

2 - started jenkins and installed git/rake/rvm plugins

3 - managed to run bundle exec spec after installing rails in "/Users/me/.jenkins/workspace/myp-project"

4 - But I am getting an error while running a build on jenkins interface

```
 $ bundle exec rake spec
 FATAL: rake execution failed
 java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "bundle"
 (in directory "/Users/me/.jenkins/workspace/my-project"): error=2, No such file or directory
```

any pointers how can I fix this ?

Comment: you need to install bundler

Comment: I did installed bundler problem is it is not picking up by jenkins

Answer (score 1):

I recently faced the same issue
When running from Console everything is ok , when running from execute shell all is alright when in Jenkins the Jenkins-man simply could not execute "gem" or "bundler" or X sample :

```html
18:20:40 Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: An Ant BuildException has occured: Execute failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "bundler" (in directory "/home/builder/lcg-qa-jenkins-slave/workspace/delete_me2/target/src/main"): error=2, No such file or directory
18:20:40 around Ant part ...<exec failonerror="false" dir="target/src/main" executable="bundler">... @ 78:76 in /home/builder/lcg-qa-jenkins-slave/workspace/delete_me2/target/antrun/build-main.xml
```

The error is totally misleading as the files do exist but for some weird reason cannot pick up executable stuff from /.rbenv/shims.
I tried uninstalling - reinstalling through numerous official and unofficial rbenv or rvm and each time got the same issue with Jenkins.
Note that this only occurs on Jenkins when Jenkins is executing while works perfect when actually running from the actual Jenkins slave or running localy.
My issue is solved with getting those executables with simlinks to /usr/bin
So when you see jenkins doing the I cant execute thingy.. then symlink the executables:

sudo ln -sfn /home/builder/.rbenv/shims/bundler  /usr/bin/bundler

None of the below additions to the 'execute shell' in Jenkins had any effect at all when previous tries:

```html
##!/bin/bash
#export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin:$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$HOME/.rbenv/shims
#eval "$(rbenv init -)"
#rbenv local
#rbenv rehash
#export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/shims:$PATH"
#echo "$PATH"
#echo 'source "/etc/profile.d/rvm.sh"' >> ~/.bashrc
#echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc
```